# Azure devops upload log file in release

Tags: azure-devops

After a deployment in linux server from azure devops, I am want to copy a log file from linux server and display in azure devops.In ssh task i tried the following command `echo ##vso[task.uploadfile]/xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxx/log/xxxxxx/console-20200625.log` the task is successful but can't find the log file.

Comment: Do you use the self-hosted agent installed on the linux server to run the pipeline?

Comment: The agent used is a self hosted windows agent. I run via SSH task from azure devops to communicate to linux server for executing a script for deployment.

Comment: is it possible to copy a file from linux server to azure devops windows agent.??`scp /xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxx/log/xxxxxx/console-20200625.log username@xxx.xx.x.xx:/C:/Users/xxxx`. i tried SCP as well but got connection refused error

Comment: You can use [Remote Copy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=saeidbabaei.remotecopysaeid&targetId=0933e8b2-f504-4b7e-9e9e-ce303b05ea59) task to copy the file from linux server to your self-hosted agent.

Answer (score 0):

[UploadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#uploadsummary-add-some-markdown-content-to-the-build-summary): Upload a file that can be downloaded with task logs:    `##vso[task.uploadfile]local file path`

`task.uploadfile` is to upload a local file to the pipeline. Since you are using a self-hosted windows agent,so the file on the linux server is not uploaded.

As workaround , you can try to use [Remote Copy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=saeidbabaei.remotecopysaeid&targetId=0933e8b2-f504-4b7e-9e9e-ce303b05ea59) task to copy the file from linux server to your self-hosted agent. Then upload this file from the local agent.

In Remote Copy task, you can specify the remote machine IP address in the `Remote Machine` field and the destination path for copy in the `Destination` field. It can be on local machine or on remote machine.